Github Action: can't access to a file through a shared github action
I have a shared workflows and actions repo, that is used by another organization repositories, one of that actions, it's responsible to set env vars which are defined on a repository local file, that is located on .github/variables/local-vars.env on Repo1:
Repo1 - local-vars.env

var1=value1 var1
var2=value2

Repo1 - Workflow
name: Build and Publish Libs to AWS CodeArtifact

on: [push]

permissions:   
id-token: write
contents: write   
actions: write  
checks: write

jobs:   format:
  uses: ORG/org-shared-workflows/.github/workflows/format.yaml@master
  with:
   local-vars: '.github/workflows/variables/local-vars.env'

Shared Workflow Repo
On the ORG/org-shared-workflows, I have the corresponding Format Workflow, that call the set-vars action
- name : Set Variables
  if: github.event_name != 'workflow_dispatch' || github.event.inputs.local-vars != ''
  uses: ORG/org-shared-workflows/actions/set-vars@master
  with:
    varFilePath: "${{ inputs.local-vars }}"

set-vars action
name: 'Set environment variables'
inputs:
  varFilePath:
    required: true
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
      sed "" ${{ inputs.varFilePath }} >> $GITHUB_ENV
      shell: bash

When I test the Workflow, and print the filesystem contents of the Repo1, the local-vars.env file is present, but the sed command fails with the follwing output

sed: can't read ./.github/workflows/variables/local-vars.env: No such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.


Below the ls command output
Run ls -la ./   
      ls -la ./.github/   
      ls -la./.github/variables/

drwxrwxr-x  5 runner runner    4096 Dec 31 11:16 .
drwxrwxr-x  3 runner runner    4096 Dec 31 11:16 ..
drwxrwxr-x  8 runner runner    4096 Dec 31 11:16 .git
drwxrwxr-x  4 runner runner    4096 Dec 31 11:16 .github

drwxrwxr-x 4 runner runner 4096 Dec 31 11:16 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 runner runner 4096 Dec 31 11:16 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 runner runner 4096 Dec 31 11:16 variables
drwxrwxr-x 2 runner runner 4096 Dec 31 11:16 workflows
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 runner runner 4096 Dec 31 11:16 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 runner runner 4096 Dec 31 11:16 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 runner runner  448 Dec 31 11:16 local-vars.env

How can I access the file located in Repo1, which I think is available from the set-vars action?
